# This method requires a body instead of a semicolon

Tags: java

Selected lines "<------- These" gives an erroror: This method requires a body instead of a semicolon

Both files must work together. 
How to fix it I need quick help. Does anyone have any idea but i dont?

```
package API.Info;

import Mains.MiniEvents;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class ApiInfo {
    public static MiniEvents plugin;

    public ApiInfo(MiniEvents plugin) {
        ApiInfo.plugin = plugin;
    }

    /**
     * @return number of players in the event.
     */
    public int eventSize() {
        return plugin.getInfo().eventSize();
    }

    /**
     * @return "code" name of the current event running; else, "none"
     * It will return one of the following:
     * horse, koth, oitc, paint, tdm, ko, lms, parkour, spleef, tnt
     */
    public String getEventName() {
        return plugin.getInfo().getEventName();
    }

    /**
     * @return TRUE if an event is starting (counting down).
     */
    public boolean eventStarting(){
        return plugin.getInfo().eventStarting();
    }

    /**
     * @return TRUE if an event has started.
     */
    public boolean eventStarted();     <------- These

    /**
     * @param player - Player to check.
     * @return TRUE if a player is currently playing in an event.
     */
    public boolean inEvent(Player player);     <------- These

    /**
     * @return the "formal" name of an event that is running.
     * param eventName - the event for which to return the formal name for.
     */
    public String eventFormalEventName(String eventName);     <------- These

    /**
     * @return time left until the event starts
     */
    public int getTimeLeft();     <------- These

    /**
     * @param player - Gets that player's file.
     * @return the FileConfiguration where individual player data is stored.
     */
    public FileConfiguration getPlayerFile(Player player);     <------- These

    /**
     * The is a big "inevent" HashSet<Player> that contains a player no matter what event
     * that player is in.
     *
     * @return the "inevent" HashSet.
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getPlayersInEvent();     <------- These

    /**
     * @return true if a player is currently in spectate mode.
     */
    public boolean inSpectateMode(Player player);     <------- These

}



File Info.jar 
package Util.Methods;

import API.Info.ApiInfo;
import Mains.MiniEvents;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Scoreboard;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Info extends ApiInfo{
    public MiniEvents plugin;


    public Info(MiniEvents plugin) {
        super(plugin);
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
    public boolean eventstarting = false;
    public boolean eventstarted = false;
    public boolean cancelled = false;
    public final HashSet<String> sbefore = new HashSet<>();
    public final HashSet<String> sblue = new HashSet<>();
    public final HashSet<String> sred = new HashSet<>();
    public final HashSet<String> sfire = new HashSet<>();
    public final HashMap<String, String> inevent = new HashMap<>();
    public final HashMap<String, Scoreboard> scoreboard = new HashMap<>();

    public int eventSize(){
        return inevent.size();
    }
    public String getEventName(){
        return plugin.getEventName();

    }
    public boolean eventStarting(){
        return eventstarting;
    }
    public boolean eventStarted(){
        return eventstarted;
    }
    public boolean inEvent(Player player){
        return inevent.containsKey(player.getName());
    }
    public String eventFormalEventName(String s){
        return plugin.getFormalName(s);
    }
    public int getTimeLeft(){
        return plugin.getTimerMain().getTimeLeft();
    }
    public FileConfiguration getPlayerFile(Player player){
        return plugin.playerFile(player.getName().toLowerCase());
    }
    public HashMap<String, String> getPlayersInEvent(){
        return inevent;
    }
    public boolean inSpectateMode(Player player){
        return plugin.getSpectateMode().inspec.contains(player.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to make them abstract methods?

Comment: Single lines give an error

Comment: @JonSkeet this is the answer ( perhaps too abstract :-) ).

Comment: @JonSkeet Skeet what do you mean?

Comment: What did you *intend* those methods to do? You've declared a concrete method, but not provided a body. It's entirely unclear what you're trying to achieve or why you're confused... what you've done simply isn't valid Java, for exactly the reason the compiler has stated.

Comment: and please split two different java class in two different files ( here it looks like ApiInfo and Info are in same file.

Comment: Each of the lines that have a problem are methods without any method bodies defined.  It looks like you copied the code from an abstract class but did not implement any of the method stubs as Jon Skeet said in his comment.  For a definition of an abstract class, look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to define a method without defining it. Methods (when not being abstract or declared in interfaces) always need the method head (`void method()`) and a body (`{ ... }`). In the lines you have marked, you are only defining the head but not the body.

If you want to have this method declared without instantly defining the body, you need to make them abstract.